# Is there a way to disable the Scribble option in Apple Pencil Settings in the Flutter app?

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm making a drawing app that uses an iPad and an Apple Pencil. When Scribble on the Apple Pencil is enabled, drawing through the `GestureDetector()` will not be smooth drawing.So I need to disable the Scribble option on the Apple Pencil .
Apple Pencils have the Scribble option enabled by default. Is there a way to automatically disable this when the app is using it? (Not controlled by the user directly from the options)

And can I detect the tap of Apple Pencil on Flutter?  (For example, if I use the tabs on the Apple Pencil, change to the Eraser Tool)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since Flutter 3.3, Scribble handwriting input is supported using the Apple Pencil on iPadOS. It is enabled by default on `CupertinoTextField`, `TextField`, and `EditableText`.

[image]

Ref: https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-3-3-893c7b9af1ff